# Is it possible to detect an table/queue/fileShare creation with eventGrid?

Tags: azure, automation, azure-storage, azure-eventgrid

In the MS documentation, at the resources of `EventGrid` `Azure Blob Storage` as event sources. There is nothing about table/queue/fileShare creations.

I saw also custom events in `EventGrid`, so i wondered if it is possible to use table/queue/fileShare creations as custom events. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way you can pass events like table/queue/fileshare creation to Event grid. Event grid supports mostly blob actions like what is listed [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema).

As a work around, you can look at is using alerts. Click on "Alerts" under the Monitoring tab on the left pane of your storage account. There are different types of actions available by which you can pass the administrative events to Azure functions, logic apps or webhooks. If you really need the events in Event grid, you can use logic apps/functions to pass those events/alerts to Event grid.

You may need to do some more filtering before doing this though to get exactly what you want. Else you may end up getting all the admin activities which I don't think you would need.
For example, what I setup below alerted me on creation and deletion of queues(among other things). I would also get alerts for List of storage keys and other admin activities.

[image]